# Find the power dissipated by the controller source

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am confused about the controller source. How can we define the controller source? I cannot figure out which one is the controller source.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The controlling source is \$ V_o \$ and the controlled source is \$ 2 \times V_o \$ as shown by the diamond symbol.

Step 1 is to find I which we calculating by noting.

\$ V_o = I \times 4\, \Omega \$ and \$ I = -(10\,\text{A} + 2\,\text{S} \times (4\, \Omega \times I)) = -(10\,\text{A} + 8 \times I) \$

Solve this for \$ I \$ and we can calculate both the current in the controlled source and the voltage across it.  From there we can calculate power dissipation.

The power dissipation in the the controlling source is simply \$P =  I^2 \times R \$

Note: since voltage and current are fundamentally different quantities we need to to know the scaling factor. I am assuming 1 ampere per volt i.e \$ 1\,\text{S} \$.

Comment: Simply as it can be, writing 2Vo they somehow mean 2S x Vo , siemens times volt gives amperes. I'd rather fix your formula where you seem to add volts and amperes though

Comment: Edited as reqquested.